# Overriden method in ViewController

Tags: extjs

I'm ExtJS 5 newbie who tries to utilize best practices of MVVM architecture. As far as my understanding of the pattern goes, one should avoid placing any logic directly in the view in favor of controller and so trying to achieve that I did something like this:

```
Ext.define(
    'MyNamespace.MyComponent',
    {
        extend: 'Ext.Component',

        requires: [
            "MyNamespace.MyController"
        ],

        controller: 'mycontroller',

        alias: "widget.mycomponent",

        onBoxReady: "myOnBoxReady"
    }
)
```

whereas my controller looked like this:

```
Ext.define(
    'MyNamespace.MyController',
    {
        extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

        alias: 'controller.mycontroller',

        myOnBoxReady: function(owner, width, height, eOpts){
            //some logic
        }
    }
)
```

What I actually managed to achieve, was receiving error `string is not a function`. So the question is - What am I doing wrong and what is the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your component like this:

```
listeners:{
    boxready:'myOnBoxReady'
}
```

Otherwise it's OK.

Comment: I've read somewhere that specifying listeners in class definition is considered bad habit, so I didn't pursue this path. If that's the only way however then... oh well :)

Comment: It was never a bad habit, however, before Ext 5 it could be problematic to set them up during the class definition (no class instance, so no access to its scope, other properties, etc.)